# How to retrieve 500k records DB data faster?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables T1 1 000 records and T2 with 500 000 records. I have a query where I run a join between them and fetch data by performing some aggregations. My page seems to be loading slow. Are there any approaches to make this query faster?

I have created indexes on columns for which aggregations are being performed. I think it is a generic statement.

```
      $query = Mymodel::selectRaw("supplier_data.name as distributor,supplier_data.name as name, supplier_data.group_id as group_id, supplier_data.pay,supplier_data.group_id as submitted_group_plan,supplier_data.group_id as group_id_string,
            (SELECT sum(t.net_claim) AS trans_number 
            FROM transactions_data_new as t 
            JOIN  `supplier_data` AS d ON  `t`.`member_id` =  `d`.`group_id`
            WHERE
            (
                (
                t.`submit_date`>= '$date_from' and t.`submit_date`<= '$date_to' 
                AND t.`member_id` = supplier_data.group_id
                )
                OR
                (
                    (t.claim_status  IS NULL)
                    AND
                    (t.submit_date is NULL)
                )
            )
            AND d.id = supplier_data.id
        ) as trans_number,


        (SELECT sum(t.claim) AS trans_number 
            FROM transactions_data_new as t 
            JOIN  `supplier_data` AS d ON  `t`.`member_id` =  `d`.`group_id`
            WHERE
            (
                (
                t.`submit_date`>= '$date_from' and t.`submit_date`<= '$date_to' 
                AND t.`member_id` = supplier_data.group_id
                )
                OR
                (
                    (t.claim_status  IS NULL)
                    AND
                    (t.submit_date is NULL)
                )
            )
            AND d.id = supplier_data.id
        ) as claim,

        (SELECT sum(t.reversed) AS trans_number 
            FROM transactions_data_new as t 
            JOIN  `supplier_data` AS d ON  `t`.`member_id` =  `d`.`group_id`
            WHERE
            (
                (
                t.`submit_date`>= '$date_from' and t.`submit_date`<= '$date_to' 
                AND t.`member_id` = supplier_data.group_id
                )
                OR
                (
                    (t.claim_status  IS NULL)
                    AND
                    (t.submit_date is NULL)
                )
            )
            AND d.id = supplier_data.id
        ) as reversed,

        (SELECT sum(t.reversal) AS trans_number 
            FROM transactions_data_new as t 
            JOIN  `supplier_data` AS d ON  `t`.`member_id` =  `d`.`group_id`
            WHERE
            (
                (
                t.`submit_date`>= '$date_from' and t.`submit_date`<= '$date_to'
                AND t.`member_id` = supplier_data.group_id
                )
                OR
                (
                    (t.claim_status  IS NULL)
                    AND
                    (t.submit_date is NULL)
                )
            )
            AND d.id = supplier_data.id
        ) as reversal
            ");
```

Comment: ["Lakh"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) as a unit name is used in official and other contexts in Bangladesh, Bhutan, India, Myanmar, Nepal, Pakistan, and Sri Lanka. *But nowhere else is it used.* 500,000 is "half a million" or "five hundred thousand"

Comment: use pagintion for this kind of

Comment: please don't reference the code from some external source, just include it into your question.

Comment: @Used_By_Already corrected question as per your suggestions.  Do u have any solution or suggestions for this?

Comment: @kunal Have already implemented Pagination. But still not satisfied with the output.

Comment: @user7325973 you can use 100 records in per page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the need of this too complex/repeated with same clauses and multiple sub selects for same table which can done using a single left join

```
SELECT 
  s.name AS distributor,
  s.name AS name,
  s.group_id AS group_id,
  s.pay,
  s.group_id AS submitted_group_plan,
  s.group_id AS group_id_string,
  SUM(t.net_claim) AS trans_number,
  SUM(t.claim) AS claim,
  SUM(t.reversed) reversed,
  SUM(t.reversal) reversal 
FROM
  supplier_data s 
  LEFT JOIN transactions_data_new t 
    ON `t`.`member_id` = s.`group_id` 
    AND (
      (
        t.`submit_date` >= '$date_from' 
        AND t.`submit_date` <= '$date_to'
      ) 
      OR (
        t.claim_status IS NULL 
        AND t.submit_date IS NULL
      )
    ) 
GROUP BY s.name,
  s.group_id,
  s.pay
```

Comment: Tax for the optimization Khalid. Just wanted to know do we have any best practices to make our data run faster. Just to quote an example Apps like Google , FB, Linkedin and many popular apps instead of having so huge data how do they run like a spark. I do use AWS for my data hosting. Do we have to use any addition plugins or any packages to make huge data run smoother?

Comment: @user7325973 It relates more to the server architecture but i not that much expert but it may involve multiple dedicated server with caching techniques load balancers , multiple data centers etc you need to research about that here is a sample [stackoverflow server architecture](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/) which can help you as where to start, For best practice its always better to follow official docs and research

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it the chunk() method is for use when you need to work with a large dataset and take an action on that data chunk by chunk.

From your question, it sounds like you're performing a query then returning the data as JSON so to me, it doesn't sound like you're taking an action on your dataset that requires chunking.

If you want to break up the returned JSON data you should be instead looking at pagination.

You could apply pagination to your query like so:

```
$data = Inspector::latest('id')
    ->select('id', 'firstname', 'status', 'state', 'phone')
    ->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchtext . '%')
    ->paginate();
```

You can specify the size of each set by passing a number to the paginate method:

```
$data = Inspector::latest('id')
    ->select('id', 'firstname', 'status', 'state', 'phone')
    ->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchtext . '%')
    ->paginate(25);
```

If I've misunderstood and you did actually want to do the chunking, I believe you could do the following:

```
$data = Inspector::latest('id')
    ->select('id', 'firstname', 'status', 'state', 'phone')
    ->where('firstname', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchtext . '%')
    ->chunk(50, function($inspectors) {
        foreach ($inspectors as $inspector) {
            // apply some action to the chunked results here
        }
    });
```

Also, if you're returning an eloquent object it will be automatically cast to json so you don't need to perform json_encode() as far as I'm aware.